# How to extract/split SQL statements in a huge .sql file to get only certain tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 22GB .sql file (100+ tables) and i only need, let's say, 5 of them. I have tried all oracle tools, but none of them is capable of extracting only specific tables.

Is there ANY way to extract only specific tables ?

Comment: I made once a small (java) application to split the sql in hundreds of well contained files. So go ahead.

Comment: Sound like a good - but also dirty - idea. I dont know the table names and the structure of the statements. I mean, its not really possible to "look into" a 22GB file

Comment: Under Linux `tail`. But you could start with splitting at 100 KB, for a couple of parts, and refine that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stumpled over a very interesting script that creates a single .sql for each table that exists in the huge main .sql: MYSQLDUMPSPLITTER.sh

http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script

In case the link is 404, please see the github gist [here](https://gist.github.com/panique/5896376).

Answer (score 8):

If you created the file with `mysqldump`, I believe you can use text utilities to extract the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

Specifically, you can use [`sed` addresses](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) to extract all the lines between two regular expressions. It won't have trouble with a 22 gig file.

I dumped my sandbox database (a small database I use mainly for answering questions on SO) for testing.

In the version of MySQL that I have installed here, this sed one-liner extracts the CREATE table statement and INSERT statements for the table "DEP_FACULTY".

```
$ sed -n -e '/^CREATE TABLE `DEP_FACULTY`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' mysql.sql > output.file
```

This regular expression identifies the start of the CREATE TABLE statement.

- /^CREATE TABLE `DEP_FACULTY`/

CREATE TABLE statements seem to always be immediately followed by INSERT statements. So we just need a regular expression that identifies the end of the INSERT statements.

- /UNLOCK TABLES/

If your version of `mysqldump` produces the same output, you should be able to just replace the table name, change the name of the output file to something meaningful, and go drink a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the dump, then you should go back and create a new one with --tables option.

mysqldump --tables table1 table2 table3

If you didn't then just load the whole database, do the above and then blow it away.